# Getting segmentation fault in loop

Tags: c++, loops, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with this code :

```
while(true){
    BCNP(CBCV[CBCV.size()-1]);
    CBCV.pop_back();
    printf("BCN : %f\n", BCN());
    for(int q = 0; q < numNode; q++){
        CurrentNode = ((MobileNode*)Node::get_node_by_address(q));
        if(CurrentNode->ConditionNeighbor == BCN()){
            printf("currentnode : %f\n", CurrentNode->ConditionNeighbor);
            tcl.evalf("$ns_ at %f \"$node_(%d) color red\"",NOW,CurrentNode->nodeid());
            tcl.evalf("$ns_ at %f \"$node_(%d) label \\\"CH\\\"\"",NOW,CurrentNode->nodeid());
            break;
        }
    }
    CurrentNode->isCluster = true;
    for(int q = 0; q < CurrentNode->NodeQueue; q++){
        neighbor = ((MobileNode*)Node::get_node_by_address(CurrentNode->neib[q]));
        //if(neighbor->isCluster == false){
            neighbor->chFlag = true;
            CurrentNode->chFlag = true;
            neighbor->cluster = CurrentNode->nodeid();
            //printf("chFlag True : %d\n", neighbor->nodeid());
        //}
    }
    notRouted_ = 0;
    for(int q = 0; q < numNode; q++){
        CurrentNode = ((MobileNode*)Node::get_node_by_address(q));
        if(CurrentNode->chFlag == false){
            notRouted_++;
            //printf("CurrentNode : %d\n",CurrentNode->nodeid());
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me a segmentation fault but i don't know where am i missing something...
it seems that a variable is not defined and in the loop it'll use that variable and that's why i'm getting this error...
i haven't sleep last night at all and now my mind is turning off , i really need help.
it would be the best if someone just give me an idea about this error.

```
    void            BCNP(double bcneighb){ BCN_ = bcneighb; };<br/>
    inline double   BCN(){ return BCN_; };
    inline int32_t  notRouted(){ return notRouted_; };
    int32_t numNode;
    std::vector<nsaddr_t> clusters;
    std::vector<double> CBCV; // __Could Be Cluster Vector
    double BCN_; // __Biggest Condition Neighbor
    int32_t notRouted_; // __number of nodes that have no cluster
    // CurrentNode is a class
    bool chFlag; // in CurrentNode
    double ConditionNeighbor; // CurrentNode
    numNode = 80;
    notRouted_ = 0;
    BCN_ = 0;
```

Comment: If you don't know where the crash happens, it's time for you to learn how to use debuggers. Running your program in a debugger will catch the crash, allowing you to examine the function call stack, and walk up the call stack to your code (if the debugger stops in e.g. a library function). When you reach your code you can examine the values of variables to help you understand why the crash happened. At the very least, you should try and use a debugger to pinpoint the location of the crash, and tell us where it is.

Comment: You should run your code in the debugger and step through line by line to find the source of the segmentation fault.

Comment: thanks for replying fast..And debug is something that can't be done because i'm using Network Simulator 2(NS2) and you can't just debug c++ codes in NS2 because it is an open source software that we are just using it and it have sooooo many includes and i just tried to debug it or even run it but it isn't a program that runs like that...The way we use it is like This: we create our protocol and our scenario and then we run the scenario by using ./ns ./scenario.tcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check for `nullptr` just after changing `CurrentNode`and `neighbor`

Like:

```
CurrentNode = ((MobileNode*)Node::get_node_by_address(q));
if (CurrentNode == nullptr)
{
    cout << "Real bad version 1..." << endl;
}
else
{
    // Your normal code...
    if(CurrentNode->ConditionNeighbor == BCN()){
        printf("currentnode : %f\n", CurrentNode->ConditionNeighbor);
        tcl.evalf("$ns_ at %f \"$node_(%d) color red\"",NOW,CurrentNode->nodeid());
        tcl.evalf("$ns_ at %f \"$node_(%d) label \\\"CH\\\"\"",NOW,CurrentNode->nodeid());
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you migth find the error to be dereference of a nullptr.

Remember to add similar code whenever a pointer is changed.

Comment: it says "error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: hmmm... try `std::nullptr` or just `null`

Comment: sorry for my late reply,i fell sleep at work,i was so  tired,but let me say this that, this was the best answer that someone could give it to me.thanks